# Переопределить gem Devise (Ruby on Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems, devise

Я использую gem Devise для реализаци авторизации для сайта. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне нужно убрать проверку авторизирован ли пользователь, когда регистрирую новый аккаунт(то есть я хочу сделать, что бы можно было создать новый аккаунт, при этом быть авторизиованным). Но в registrations_controller все методы наследуют уже готовую реализацию и я не знаю как можно переопределить эти методы. Подскажите как можно переопределить или изменить начальную реализацию этих методов.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

#before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
#before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

def new
 super
end

def create
 super
end

def edit
 super
end


def update
 super
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело там не в самих экшнах, проверка аутентификации находится в [фильтре](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

```
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
```

Соответственно, вам нужно всего лишь отключить этот фильтр при создании нового пользователя

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```